# shower pan inspection

Tags: shower, tile

When is a shower pan typically inspected? After the PVC membrane is installed and before the mud deck is put on above this, or after the mud deck and drain grate are installed?

Comment: The contractor / builder will typically check it for leaks before the upper mud deck is put on top of the PVC membrane. That way it's cheap to repair or replace.

Answer (score 1):

It would be tested for leaks before the top layer of mortar was laid up over the PVC membrane.

Comment: I can do a leak test then, but do I call the inspector then, or after the next layer of mud?

Comment: I would ask the inspector that question